# Proof that a piecewise function is invertible.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Prove that the following function is invertible: $$g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$$

$$
  g(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
      -2x & : x\le0\\
      2x-1 & : x>0
    \end{array}
  \right.
$$

I'm having an issue proving that it is one-to-one in all cases. The cases where $x_{1},x_{2}\le0$ and $x_{1},x_{2}>0$ both pass proof by contrapostitive where $g(x_{1})=g(x_{2})$. I'm having a problem proving it is also one-to one if $x_{1}\le0$ but $x_{2}>0$ which would result in:

$$
-2x_{1}=2x_{2}-1
$$
$$
x_{1}=-x_{2}+\frac{1}{2}
$$

I know I'm going something wrong in my thinking and I have a sneaking suspicion it has something to do with the fact that I'm mapping to $\mathbb{N}$, but I'm completely unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: Are you sure that $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$? Because if $x=\sqrt{2}$, then surely $g(x)$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. Let me edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-2x$ will always give you a nonnegative, even integer, when $x \leq 0$.  And, $-2x$ is strictly decreasing.  $2x - 1$ will always give a positive, odd integer, when $x > 0$.  And, $2x - 1$ is strictly increasing.  That's all you need.

Comment: Thanks, I think that makes sense. Normally I do have to prove that $g(x_{1})=g(x_{2})$, but what you're saying is in the third case I can apply a direct proof showing that it is impossible for an element to map to multiple elements in the co-domain since $x_{1}$ would always be even and $x_{2}$ would always be odd. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @kamikazekent Correct.  Injective means that $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ implies $x_1 = x_2$.  Or, equivalently, the contrapositive is $x_1 \neq x_2$ implies $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$.  So, pick two $x$ values that are both $x \leq 0$.  The fact that the function is strictly decreasing implies $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$.  Similarly if your two $x$ values are both $> 0$.  And, if one is nonpositive and one is positive, then $g(x_1)$ is even and $g(x_2)$ is odd, so they're not equal then also.